# Problem creating gnu makefile "function"

Tags: makefile

I have a big chunk of my makefile (~50 lines) that needs to be copy-pasted 5 times for different case (the different libraries used). Is it possible to create a function in a makefile and just call that function instead of copy-pasting?

This is an example of what I've tried. Basically this tries to find the right path for an installed library.

```
define Flags_template
$(1)_include_home      := $(HOME)/usr/include
$(1)_include_home_name := $(HOME)/usr/include/$(1)

ifneq ($$(wildcard $($(1)_include_home)/$(2)),)
    $(1)_Include := $$($(1)_include_home)
else
    ifneq ($$(wildcard $($(1)_include_home_name)/$(2)),)
        $(1)_Include := $$($(1)_include_home_name)
    endif
endif

CFLAGS += -I$$($(1)_Include)

endef

$(eval $(call Flags_template,stdcout,StdCout.hpp))

.PHONY: test
test:
    # stdcout_include_home_name = $(stdcout_include_home_name)
    # stdcout_Include = $(stdcout_Include)
    # CFLAGS: $(CFLAGS)
```

Typing "make", I get this output:

```
# stdcout_include_home_name = /home/nicolas/usr/include/stdcout
# stdcout_Include = 
# CFLAGS: -I
```

It's so close. But note the last "-I", I always get dupplicates, one fully expended, one empty...

I don't understant what needs to be eval'ed, escaped with two $, etc.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does §8.8 of the GNU Make (3.82) manual help?

> [...] Although it might seem overly complex to use eval in this example,
>   rather than just writing out the rules, consider two things: first, the template definition (in
>   PROGRAM_template) could need to be much more complex than it is here; and second, you
>   might put the complex, “generic” part of this example into another makefile, then include
>   it in all the individual makefiles. Now your individual makefiles are quite straightforward.

```
PROGRAMS = server client
server_OBJS = server.o server_priv.o server_access.o
server_LIBS = priv protocol
client_OBJS = client.o client_api.o client_mem.o
client_LIBS = protocol
# Everything after this is generic
.PHONY: all
all: $(PROGRAMS)
define PROGRAM_template =
        $(1): $$($(1)_OBJS) $$($(1)_LIBS:%=-l%)
        ALL_OBJS += $$($(1)_OBJS)
endef
$(foreach prog,$(PROGRAMS),$(eval $(call PROGRAM_template,$(prog))))
$(PROGRAMS):
        $(LINK.o) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
clean:
        rm -f $(ALL_OBJS) $(PROGRAMS)
```

---

### This Works (For Me)

This is the output from the GNU makefile just below:

```
stdcout_include_home = /work4/jleffler/usr/include
stdcout_include_home_name = /work4/jleffler/usr/include/stdcout
stdcout_Include = /work4/jleffler/usr/include
CFLAGS: -I/work4/jleffler/include -I/work4/jleffler/usr/include
```

#### GNU Makefile

```
CFLAGS = -I${HOME}/include

define Flags_template
$(1)_include_home      := $(HOME)/usr/include
$(1)_include_home_name := $(HOME)/usr/include/$(1)

ifneq ($$(wildcard $$($(1)_include_home)/$(2)),)
    $(1)_Include := $$($(1)_include_home)
else
    ifneq ($$(wildcard $$($(1)_include_home_name)/$(2)),)
        $(1)_Include := $$($(1)_include_home_name)
    else
        $(1)_Include := Neither $$($(1)_include_home) nor $$($(1)_include_home_name) contains $2
    endif
endif

CFLAGS += -I$$($(1)_Include)

endef

$(eval $(call Flags_template,stdcout,StdCout.hpp))

.PHONY: test
test:
        @echo stdcout_include_home = $(stdcout_include_home)
        @echo stdcout_include_home_name = $(stdcout_include_home_name)
        @echo stdcout_Include = $(stdcout_Include)
        @echo CFLAGS: $(CFLAGS)
```

The difference is in the wildcard invocations:

```
ifneq ($$(wildcard  $($(1)_include_home)/$(2)),)    # Fails
ifneq ($$(wildcard $$($(1)_include_home)/$(2)),)    # Works
```

I have half an intuition about when double-dollars and when single-dollars are needed; I am not sure I can articulate the decision, though.

Comment: Yes this is the inspiration I had. I'll change the code to simplify it. But I can't reproduce the behaviour I want. I always get dupplicated CFLAGS.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. So a single, damn $ made it failed... :S
But now it works!